# Python 3 File Indexing Parallel

Tags: python, file, indexing

I have a question about python 3 file indexing.
I have a code, it will list all file in my Computer into a file named test.txt.
All I wanna do is to make this code paralel for faster processing time.

```
import os
import time

start = time.time()
handle = open("test.txt","w")

rootDir = '/'
for dirName, subdirList, fileList in os.walk(rootDir):
    for fname in fileList:
        handle.write("%s\n" %os.path.abspath(os.path.join(dirName,fname)).encode('utf-8'))

handle.close()
end = time.time()
print (end-start)
```

I hope you all can help me.
Thanks a lot and have a nice day.

Comment: You may like to carefully explore threading in Python.

Comment: You're going to have to write a faster `os.walk` then. You might try [`directory`](https://github.com/pelotoncycle/directory).  That `handle.write` line looks like it's doing a lot.  How much of that is really necessary? You should also investigate separating the walk from the file writing.  Probably the walking processes would send messages to a queue that is read by some writer process.

Comment: @VivekJain alright mate, yeah i already discover threading but feel confused about it. should i create a function that will be used to loop the indexing process?

Comment: @PatrickHaugh okay mate i will try your advice. thanks a lot